# How to solve a complex exponential functional equation which contains the multivalued argument function of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, functional-equations

I am trying to solve a complex exponential functional equation. A real to complex function $\gamma(t):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ has the following form
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)=e^{rt}\cdot e^{i(H(t)+2k\pi)}
\end{align}
where $r$ is a real constant and $k$ is any integer. $e^{rt}$ is the modulus of $\gamma(t)$ and $H(t)$ is the principle value of the argument of $\gamma(t)$. I know it satisfies the following functional equation
\begin{align}
[\gamma(t_1+t_2)]^2=[\gamma(t_1)\gamma(t_2)]^2
\end{align}
So, I plug in $\gamma(t)$ to get
\begin{align}
[e^{r(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1+t_2)+2k_1\pi)}]\cdot[e^{r(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1+t_2)+2k_2\pi)}]=[e^{rt_1}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1)+2k_3\pi)}\cdot e^{rt_2}\cdot e^{i(H(t_2)+2k_4\pi)}]\cdot[e^{rt_1}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1)+2k_5\pi)}\cdot e^{rt_2}\cdot e^{i(H(t_2)+2k_6\pi)}]
\end{align}
The real part can cancel out so that
\begin{align}
e^{i2H(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{2k_1\pi}\cdot e^{2k_2\pi}=e^{i2H(t_1)}\cdot e^{i2H(t_2)}\cdot e^{2k_3\pi}\cdot e^{2k_4\pi}\cdot e^{2k_5\pi}\cdot e^{2k_6\pi}
\end{align}
This could be further simplified as
\begin{align}
&e^{i2H(t_1+t_2)}=e^{i2H(t_1)}\cdot e^{i2H(t_2)}\cdot e^{i2k\pi}\\
&e^{i2[H(t_1+t_2)-H(t_1)-H(t_2)]}=e^{i2k\pi}
\end{align}
Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
H(t_1+t_2)-H(t_1)-H(t_2)=k\pi
\end{align}
Adding $k\pi$ to both sides of equation, this is equivalent to
\begin{align}
H(t_1+t_2)+k\pi=H(t_1)+k\pi+H(t_2)+k\pi
\end{align}
Define function $f(t)\equiv H(t)+k\pi$ so that
\begin{align}
f(t_1+t_2)=f(t_1)+f(t_2)
\end{align}
which is the Cauchy functional equation, thus $f(t)=\lambda t$ where $\lambda$ is a real number. And $H(t)=\lambda t+k\pi$ where $k$ is an integer. Eventually, $\gamma(t)=e^{rt}\cdot e^{i\lambda t+k\pi}$. Since $e^{k\pi}=-1$ when $k$ is an odd number, we have $\gamma(t)=e^{rt}\cdot e^{i\lambda t}$ or $-e^{rt}\cdot e^{i\lambda t}$.

---

Is this the correct solution?

Also, I think that $[\gamma(t_1+t_2)]^2=[e^{r(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1+t_2)+2k_1\pi)}]\cdot[e^{r(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1+t_2)+2k_2\pi)}]$ but not $[e^{r(t_1+t_2)}\cdot e^{i(H(t_1+t_2)+2k\pi)}]^2$, is this correct? The former one have different $k_1$ and $k_2$ for the square of $\gamma(t_1+t_2)$, while the latter one has only one $k$. I feel it is very tempted to write as the latter one.

Comment: Is $k$ an integer?

Comment: Yes. $k$ is any integer

Comment: Then you don't need to carry it at all.  $e^{2k\pi i}=1$

Comment: Your functional equation simplifies to $\gamma(t_1+t_2)=\pm\gamma(t_1)\gamma(t_2)$.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. Do you think it is legitimate to plug $\gamma(t)$ into the functional equation? I always have concern that since argument of complex number is a multi-valued function, it may cause some problem after plugging in. For example, $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)$ is a set equality where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are complex numbers. Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: @mr_e_man Yeah, it is actually a simplification of my original question which has coefficients of $t_1$ and $t_2$. I was worried if the same issue will still show up if I simplify it. But I will re-edit it.

Comment: It's what you are doing afterwards that seems illegitimate.  You seem to be saying $H(t_1+t_2) = H(t_1)+H(t_2)$ and I don't see where that comes from.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your comments, I tried to rewrite the solution, could you please take a look at the update solution and also the question below the solution.

Comment: @mr_e_man I rewrote the solution, the last paragraph about how to write out the square is my concern. And that was why I was reluctant to simplify the functional equation as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For $\gamma : \Bbb{R \to C^*} $ continuous satisfying $$(\gamma(t_1+t_2))^2=(\gamma(t_1)\gamma(t_2))^2
$$ 
$\log$  is an isomorphism $\Bbb{C^* \to C/2i\pi Z}$ thus applying it to both side
 $$2\log \gamma(t_1+t_2) =2 \log \gamma (t_1) + 2\log \gamma(t_2)  \in \Bbb{C/2i\pi Z}$$ 
From a solution we can lift $\log \gamma : \Bbb{R \to C/2i\pi Z}$ to a continuous 
function $\log \gamma : \Bbb{R \to C}$ whose reduction $\bmod 2i\pi$ agrees,

we'll have for some function $N : \Bbb{R\to Z}$
$$2\log \gamma(t_1+t_2) =2 \log \gamma (t_1) + 2\log \gamma(t_2)+2i \pi N(t)\in \Bbb{C}$$ 
The continuity implies $N(t)=n$ is constant which means $$\log \gamma(t) = ts+i\pi n, \qquad \gamma(t) = e^{ts} (-1)^n$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not in this field so I need sometime to understand your proof. Two quick questions. 1, what does C* mean? 2, how should I know the value of n? Because I thought the solution should be either $e^{ts}$ or $-e^{ts}$, but since you claimed that n is constant, there seems to be only one solution.

Comment: Do you know any textbook on how to treat the multi-valued argument function of complex number in functional equation? I think this is the major issue I have. Thanks.